# Elasticsearch Aggregation of Child Documents Ordered by Parent Count

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to build an aggregated list of children grouped by a specific attribute ordered by the number of parents that have a child with that attribute.

#### Example

Say I have `Garage` documents which can have many `Vehicle` documents as children:

```
# Vehicle
{
  "data": {
    "isCar": true,
    "color": "red"
  },
  "join": {
    "parent": "garage:7b387b7b-95cf-44b6-b5a7-619b434b41c5",
    "name": "vehicle"
  }
}
```

I am looking to narrow my query to cars (not all vehicles) and get the following list as output:

```
[
  {
    "key" : "red",
    "doc_count" : 5
  },
  {
    "key" : "blue",
    "doc_count" : 2
  },
  {
    "key" : "white",
    "doc_count": 1
  }
]
```

Note that if a given `Garage` has multiple cars of a color, I still only want it to add one to my desired count. (In the previous list, there could be one garage with multiple white cars.)

I am able to get something similar to what I need with this:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "vehicle"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "data.isCar": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "data.color.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "garages": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "join#garage"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is ordered by the *number* of cars, not the number of garages with a car of a given color. I can build the same list starting my query with the parent and using a `children` aggregation, but I end up with the same problem.

For context, I am using elasticsearch 6.5.4

Comment: Could you share your mapping details?

Comment: @Kamal - this is just an example, but it would be something like:

`"mappings":{ "properties": { "join": { "type": "join", "relations": { "garage": "vehicle" } } } } `